# Google Places API Web Service getUrl returning invalid URL

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api, google-places

Google Places API Web Service For Javascript randomly started returning bad URLs when calling

```
photo.getUrl({maxWidth: 400, maxHeight: 400});
```

Keep in mind my app is doing everything perfect, not caching etc. and everything else in the web service works. The weird part is the fact it returns a URL that is just plain invalid. I am using this service within an Ionic app.

Example Returned URL: 
    https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/w400-h400-p/AF1QipPB7DYeNrzI7wCylJXOUwodGyGOS691HnZ5maFx=k

This is pretty much breaking my entire app, and I do not know any way to solve it. It started happening yesterday around 2:00 PM. The Service has worked flawlessly for about 2 months now.

Answer (score 1):

It was a bug on Google side reported in the public issue tracker:

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/63298126

As of time of writing the bug is marked as Fixed, so you should be OK now.